# Tkinter Scale-Widget center label

Tags: python, tkinter

Win7 Python 2.7

I have created a Scale widget, but, for a horizontal orientation, the widget wants to place the label in the top left corner.

Is there any way to center the label left to right?

I thought about not having a label in the widget, then create a label widget separately, but that seems kludgy.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: I recommend not having a label in the widget, then creating a label widget separately :-)

Comment: The widget doesn't give you that kind of control, so I'd have to agree with @Bryan. [Some documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/scale.html) I frequently use says, in part, that "The label appears in the top left corner if the scale is horizontal, or the top right corner if vertical".

Comment: That is what I am finding, bummer.